# postgres VIEW table

Tags: postgresql

Читаю книжку, и потихоньку пытаюсь применить знания. Создал в миграциях view таблицу, чтобы в дальнейшем обращаться к ней, и не делать кучу запросов с join/groupBy/OrderBy.

Нормальная ли это практика? Смогу ли я эту виртуальную таблицу сортировать по созданным там полям нормально? смогу ли я производить какие нибудь операции с обновлением\удалением по ней?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Нормальная ли это практика?

Нормальная, но стоит помнить, что обычное представление просто хранит запрос и подставляет его вместо обращения по его имени, так что это является лишь синтаксическим сахаром и средством поддержки API-совместимости. Ни каких оптимизаций оно не даёт, все `join`/`group By`/`Order By` будут выполняться заново при каждом обращении к оному. Существуют также [`MATERIALIZED VIEW`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/rules-materializedviews.html), но это уже по сути является временная таблица и совсем другая история.

> Смогу ли я эту виртуальную таблицу сортировать по созданным там полям нормально?

В зависимости от определения «нормально». Просто добавлять `ORDER BY` — да, возможно. Создавать индексы над видом — нет. Так что скорость сортировки будет зависеть от того, получится ли использовать индексы по исходным таблицам.

> смогу ли я производить какие нибудь операции с обновлением\удалением по ней?

Вообще говоря — нет. Но в тривиальных случаях, если представление является «[*обновляемым*](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html#SQL-CREATEVIEW-UPDATABLE-VIEWS)» (для этого нужно соблюдение определённых [условий](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createview.html#SQL-CREATEVIEW-UPDATABLE-VIEWS) — ни каких `JOIN`, `GROUP BY`, `UNION` и т.п.) postgresql позволяет это делать автомагически. Также для вида можно явно создать [`INSTEAD OF`-триггеры](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/plpgsql-trigger.html#PLPGSQL-VIEW-TRIGGER-AUDIT-EXAMPLE), в этом случае любой вид можно сделать для внешнего пользователя виртуально неотличимым от таблицы.